I am trying to add dependencies in flutter but I keep getting error in the android version when i try to run it
When I run my app I get this:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Victus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Victus\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Victus\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7s

I am getting this not only for this but for any other dependencies like alarm_manager_plus.
This is my build.gradle file
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

this is the gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

I don't know what to do. I went in the project structure and I put Android SDK setting as Android API 35 and for my Language Level setting as 23 - Markdown documentation comments. It doesn't work.

Basically, you need this in app\build.gradle:
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = 17
}

This in settings.gradle:

id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false


And this in gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip


Provide explanation why
